# Good beginner's guide to LaTeX programming

Tags: macros, programming, tutorials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming)

After a year of using LaTeX I've become fairly comfortable with troubleshooting common errors. As my confidence with LaTeX increases, I now find myself in situations where I wonder how I could extend a certain command's functionality for it behave it as I'd like.

The problem is, there are tons of guides to learn to typeset documents using LaTeX, but very documents on how to get to that next level.

I was hoping that some of the more advanced users in this forum would be able to point me towards some of these documents.

More specifically, topics that I'd like to cover include:

- A command manual for core LaTeX macros
- A guide to the pitfalls and precautions that should be taken when patching macros
- Package and class writing

In other words, if you're a LaTeX guru, this is the place to reminisce your beginnings and pass on some of your wisdom. Or, at least, point newer users in the right direction!

Comment: I also looking for a quick crash course of TeX programming that should skip unnecessary topics.